# Conditionally copy selected cells from one sheet to another once for each new entry

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets. On sheet 1, I have set up a macro that changes the color of the row and assigns "TRUE" value by selecting the cell or removes the color and "TRUE" value by selecting the cell again.

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Integer
Dim kod As Worksheet
Set kod = Worksheets("kodas")
  If Target.Column <> 12 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Target.Value <> "" Then
  Target.ClearContents
  Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
  Else
  Target.Value = "Taip"
  Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
  Target.EntireRow.Range(Cells(1), Cells(12)).Copy
  i = kod.Cells(2, 3)
  Sheets("Kodas2").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Kodas2").Cells(i, 1)
  End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

*The above edited code worked for me - `i = kod.Cells(2, 3)` is a cell with formula: count(table4[bla])+2 that gives the first empty row number for pasting.

I now need some additional actions to be completed upon selecting the cell -OR- upon having the "TRUE" value assigned:
(1) Specific cells from the same row to be copied and pasted to sheet 2
(2) This action to be completed only once for each row (regardless of how many times the cell is selected) - perhaps locking the row would work?

The color and "True" shows which rows from sheet1 are suitable for continued work in sheet2, where some more data will be added. I essentially want to funnel only the suitable rows into the next datasheet automatically upon entry - it is important that the values are copied to the new table ByVal and not ByRef.

Comment: Perhaps a `For...Next` loop separate from your `SelectionChange` Sub.

Comment: @Chrismas007 I was thinking of a For...Next loop but I couldn't think of a way to make it automatically copy all rows containing "TRUE" in that column only once - I want to avoid duplication of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this (not using a `For...Next Loop`):

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column <> 12 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Target.Value <> "" Then
    Target.ClearContents
    Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
  Else
    Target.Value = "TRUE"
    Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Target.EntireRow.Copy
    DestLast = Sheets("Dest Sheet Name").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheets("Dest Sheet Name").Range("A" & DestLast).Paste
  End If
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Only problem is when you select the cell again, and "turn off" the row, it will still be on your "further work" sheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, used something very similar and it worked. Used a more precise range than `Target.EntireRow.Copy` as it otherwise colors way more columns than my destination table contains.
Also, for some reason, I can never get paste commands with range to work - only works if I select the first range in the cell - otherwise I get errors related to paste. What I used may not be optimal as I needed to refer to a formula outside of the vba code but it's a quick fix I suppose.